# Amazon.S3.Model.Filter.FilterRules Listのセットの仕方

Tags: c#, aws-sdk

Listクラスの追加ですが、以下プログラムだとエラーになるのですが、どうすればよいでしょうか？
ご教示よろしくお願いいたします。

```
using Amazon.S3.Model;
Filter filter = new Filter();
filter.S3KeyFilter.FilterRules.Add(new FilterRule("hoge", "1"));
```

**エラー内容**

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Answer (score 3):

中途の `S3KeyFilter` や `FilterRules` クラスのインスタンスを作成する必要があります。

https://dotnetfiddle.net/5qxU0n

```csharp
using Amazon.S3.Model;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using ServiceStack.Text;
          
public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    Filter filter = new Filter {
      S3KeyFilter = new S3KeyFilter {
        FilterRules = new List<FilterRule> {
          new FilterRule("hoge", "1")
        }
      }
    };

    filter.S3KeyFilter.FilterRules.Add(new FilterRule("fuga", "2"));
    Console.WriteLine(filter.S3KeyFilter.FilterRules.Dump());
  }
}
```

Comment: なるほど。途中のもインスタンス生成しないといけなかったのですね。だからインスタンスがないよ！ってエラーになるのか。ご教示誠にありがとうございました！！！